# Cross-compilation Ubuntu-Win7 using a custom Makefile instead of qmake

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, cross-compiling, mxe

I've a project which uses Qt4 with no additional libraries and QtSql (for working with a SQLLite database) and I want to cross-compile it for a x86_64 Windows 7 machine. That's my summarized makefile (it uses only .hpp files, apart from main.cpp, since I make use of lots of templates):

```
CXX=g++-4.8
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -pedantic-errors -Wextra
IPATH=-I/usr/include/qt4/ -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtSql
LDFLAGS=-lQtGui -lQtSql -lQtCore

OBJS=main.o
HEADERS=mymoc1.hpp mymoc2.hpp other-headers

all: myexec

myexec: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

main.o: main.cpp $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(IPATH)

mymoc1.hpp: the-header-needing-moc.hpp
    moc $< -o $@

mymoc2.hpp: other-header-needing-moc.hpp
    moc $< -o $@
```

I am going to follow the next tutorial: http://mxe.cc/#tutorial
Supposing I've complete succesfully the first fourth steps, my doubt comes from choosing between 5c and 5d steps. What shall I use and how in my case? What does it happen with dependences like QtSql? And with moc?

Additionally, should I define LD, AR or PKG_CONFIG variables as the tutorial says? I didn't specify the linker or the assembler in my original makefile. And in case I should, why?

**EDIT** I've read [here](http://arrayfire.com/cross-compile-to-windows-from-linux/) that `mingw` has troubles working with templates, and I make a deep use of them in my project. Since MXE uses `mingw`internally, should I consider other alternatives (like build in Windows directly) instead of using MXE?

Comment: If mingw works with your code you could find out by building your project with mingw directly under Windows. I'd first make sure it builds and runs on Windows when built on Windows, before messing with cross-compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to post my own answer here, but full of details, because I was very lost and perhaps other users are in similar conditions.

> I am going to follow the next tutorial: http://mxe.cc/#tutorial Supposing I've complete successfully the first fourth steps, my doubt comes from choosing between 5c and 5d steps. What shall I use and how in my case?

Yes, you (me indeed, I'm answering my own question), can use Makefile to cross-compile a statically-linked Qt project. The problem is, as Qt is statically linked, any other Qt dependencies must be statically linked as well, and this create a potential long string of library dependencies to be added in your Makefile (and you also need to know the correct options to be passed to the linker). The problem is some of these option or libraries are beside windows-specific, so, if you have never compiled a program for Windows before, it's hard you to know what are they and what they are used for.

For this reason the best thing you can do is to write your own `.pro` file to create a working Makefile with `qmake`. At this point, if you do still want to make your custom Makefile, you can execute the `makefile` generated by `qmake` and see the executed commands, to copy back and experiment in your custom Makefile.

Anyway, I'll post the farest `makefile` I reach (later in this post I'll show how my working `*.pro` file looks like). It compiled successfully, but it crash when linking, because there was a lot of unresolved dependences I hadn't be capable to fix as said above (my mxe installation is in `/usr/local/mxe):

```
ifndef CROSS
CROSS=x86_64
endif

CROSS_ID=$(CROSS)-w64-mingw32.static
MXE_BASE=/usr/local/mxe/usr
MXE_USR=$(MXE_BASE)/$(CROSS_ID)

MXE_INCL=$(MXE_USR)/include
MXE_QTINCL=$(MXE_USR)/qt/include
MXE_LIB=$(MXE_USR)/lib
MXE_QTLIB=$(MXE_USR)/qt/lib

LDIFLAGS=-I$(MXE_INCL) -I$(MXE_QTINCL)/QtCore -I$(MXE_QTINCL)/QtGui -I$(MXE_QTINCL)/QtSql
LDLFLAGS=-L$(MXE_LIB) -L$(MXE_QTLIB)

LDLIBS=-Wl,-Bstatic -lwinmm -loleut32 -lQtGui -lQtSql -lQtCore

CXX=$(MXE_PATH)/bin/$(CROSS_ID)-g++
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wall

OBJS=main.o
MOC_HEADERS=mymoc1.hpp mymoc2.hpp
HEADERS=$(MOC_HEADERS) myheaders

APP=myapp.exe

all: $(APP)

$(APP): $(OBJS)
     $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@ $(LDLFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

main.o: main.cpp $(HEADERS)
     $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LDIFLAGS)

mymoc1: header1.hpp
     moc $< -o $@

mymoc2: header2.hpp
     moc $< -o $@

# Thee ways of call it:
#   make  # CROSS=x86_64 by default as shown in the first line.
#   make CROSS=x86_64 # Make it explicit.
#   make CROSS=i686 # Choose 32 bit.
```

> What does it happen with dependencies like QtSql?

As you see, you treat your dependencies as other normal libraries: specifying it with `-l` options, but now with `Wl,-Bstatic` (to say the linker the linking must be static), and specifying with `-L` options the exact place of the cross-compiled libraries as shown in the code above. Additionally, in that `makefile` I added `-lwinmm` and `-loleut32` because they were ones of the falling dependencies.

Anyway, this makefile don't fully compile because of the linker, but to work, you shall only to add the other indirectly required libraries and options (seeying the `qmake` generated `makefile`). Anyway, the main `configuration` issues are all of them shown in the `makefile` above.

> And with moc?

The tool `moc` is a preprocessor, and thus, machine independent (AFAIK). So, you can pass `moc` to your files using the local installation of moc. Anyway, MXE, of course, also installs a platform-specific `moc`:

```
MXE_MOC=$(MXE_USR)/qt/bin/moc

mymoc1: header1.hpp
    $(MXE_MOC) $< -o $@
```

But I don't think there's important differences between the `moc` of MXE and yours, except perhaps the MXE version is more modern (I don't know).

> Additionally, should I define LD, AR or PKG_CONFIG variables as the tutorial says?

It isn't necessary. If you don't explicitly use them, you don't need to define them.

> I've read that mingw has troubles working with templates, and I make a deep use of them in my project.

False. The current MXE version installs the `mingw32` forge of `gcc` 5.1.0, which works like a charm.

And what about the `.pro` file?

```
MXE = /usr/local/mxe/usr/$$CROSS
MXE_INCL = $$MXE/include
MXE_LIB = $$MXE/lib
MXE_QT = $$MXE/qt

MXE_QTINCL = $$MXE_QT/include
MXE_QTLIB = $$MXE_QT/lib

TARGET = myapp # .exe no required.

OBJS = main.o
MOC_HEADERS = mymoc1.hpp mymoc2.hpp
HEADERS = $$MOC_HEADERS other-headers
SOURCES = main.cpp

QMAKE_CXX = $${CROSS}-g++
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = -static -std=c++11 -pedantic -pedantinc-errors -Wall

QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Xlinker -Bstatic
INCLUDE_PATH += $$MXE_QTINCL $$MXE_QTINCL/QtGui $$MXE_QTINCL/QtSql

TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += qt release
QT += core gui sql

LIBS += -L$$MXE_QTLIB -L$$MXE_LIB

# Call it (for x86_64):
#    /usr/local/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/qt/bin/qmake\
#      -makefile -o cross_makefile -nomoc CROSS=x86_64 myapp.pro
#    make -f cross_makefile
```

As you see, I'm saying `qmake` to don't generate `moc` files (option `-nomoc`), because for some strange reason, `qmake` is not capable to find my `Q_OBJECT`s among so many templates. So, I had to generate them manually before. What I really did was to modify my original makefile (the one I use to compile my project for Linux) with a target call `cross` which generates the `moc` files and then call automatically `qmake` with the proper options.